# Insert data into MySQL with volley

Tags: java, php, android, mysql, android-volley

I have a problem uploading rows of the database in MySQL with volley. It works perfectly but I can only upload one row in the table. After that, when I try uploading another one it doesn’t work. If I unistall the app and reinstall it, it happens  the same, I can  upload only one row. However, in Xampp with a local server it works fine. The problem appears with remote servers. It is as if the session stayed open even though I introduce the closure code.

Comment: Do you have any source code that we can review?

Comment: Read [This](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: This is de php insert code. All the same php code and android app works ok in local Xampp server. Thanks.

Comment: <?php

include 'conexion.php';
$id_carga=$_POST['id_carga'];
$asuper=$_POST['asuper'];
$premium=$_POST['premium'];
$diesel=$_POST['diesel'];
$dieselp=$_POST['dieselp'];

$consulta="insert into producto(id_carga,super,premium,diesel,dieselp) VALUES ('".$id_carga."','".$asuper."','".$premium."','".$diesel."','".$dieselp."')";
mysqli_query($conexion,$consulta) or die (mysqli_error());
mysqli_close($conexion);


?>